# OpenCV channel filtering using lookup table

Tags: python, opencv, colors

I am using python OpenCV, and I am trying to speed up the real-time channel filtering process on a video. It seems using `cv2.LUT()` with a multichannel lookup table would be the way to go. The video frames are color-coded in the **HSV** color space, and **I would like to filter on value and saturation at the same time [exactly as here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882928/color-thresholding-on-an-opencv-video)**

I wrote this code, that performs a multichannel lookup and replaces colors with predefined (here, pure red) values in `self.frame`, which is an HSV input image (*i.e.* a numpy array of the shape 640 X 480 X 3) that I want to filter.

```
#create a numpy array of 256 int (= single channel of the lookup table)
lut = np.arange(256, dtype = "uint8")
#fill the lookup table with int 255
lut.fill(255)
#hue in OpenCV is 0-179, so create an array with 256 int clipped to this interval
hueLut = lut.clip(0,179)
#reshape for a 3-channels lookup table (256 X 1 X 3) array.
lut = cv2.merge((hueLut,lut,lut))
#perform lookup, here replacing every pixel with red (HSV 179, 255, 255)
self.frame = cv2.LUT(self.frame, lut, self.frame)
```

However, I do not know how to go on from here, because I do not understand how calculate the needed lookup table, even when reading the documentation.

I would like the user to be able to input 2 values (desired hue and saturation), and turn every pixel that has a hue or saturation value higher than the input to black.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain with an example, what its input is and what is the expected output?

Comment: You can use inRange function to filter all pixels within a specific values. http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#object-tracking